# jquery can fire function issue with live

Tags: jquery

I have the following function that loads "mypage.htm" into "#flowplayer-content".

This works

```
 $('.small-images a').bind("click", function(event) {

    var uri = "mypage.htm";
    $("#flowplayer-content").load(uri, null, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

"mypage.htm" contains ahref. I want to call this event.

```
$("a").live("click", function() {
    alert("handler hit");
});
```

but i can't seem to hit it

Comment: weird, this looks fine. Do you get any errors? Could you show us some code from mypage.html ?

Comment: I tested the code and works fine. You must have missed something.

Comment: I agree with the other 2 that this works fine. Are you using event.stopPropagation() in your real code and not event.preventDefault()?

Answer (score 0):

When do you call the live method? This should be called before the new HTML is loaded.

Also, the way you are doing it now affects all links, even the one that loads the html. Am I right to guess that you are using a different selector in the real thing?

Perhaps, it will be better to post the full source (javascript + html).